# .net core 2.0 web app on dokku returns 400 on every post method on digital ocean

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, digital-ocean, dokku

I deployed a new project to digital ocean on dokku droplet. The problem is that any post method with any parameter returns a 400 response.

You can test [here](http://206.189.55.62/).

Just type anything in text and press test. It will throw 400. No logs are recorded on server side and does not even enter the post method. Here is the methods of this example:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(string model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I was thinking that this is a problem about antiforgery validation but adding `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` does not solve the problem, so I'm clueless. I already wasted more than a day trying to solve this but it's helpless.

Here's my DockerFile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.sln .
COPY WebApplication2/*.csproj ./WebApplication2/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY WebApplication2/. ./WebApplication2/
WORKDIR /app/WebApplication2
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod 777 /app
COPY --from=build /app/WebApplication2/out ./
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:80
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication2.dll"]
```

How can I debug and trace the error reason?

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the excact same problem.

Comment: @IvanMonteiro Nope, we ditched digital ocean. Try aws or ibm cloud.

Comment: Actually I solved the problem. The app runs on port 5000 by default, so I added ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000 to dockerfile

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Get methods were working fine but every post method was failing. If the problem was env variable, get methods also wouldn't work. But never mind, add it as an answer so I can accept to be reference for others.